# Is my contractor doing a botched up job installing the soffit

Tags: siding, contractors, soffit, vinyl-siding

Is my contractor doing a botched up job installing the soffit with staples?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are special tips that are supposed to keep staple from delving too tight but I would check with siding manufacturer to. See their recommended method of attaching. If they don’t recommend staples your product warranty is in jeopardy

Answer (score 2):

Vinyl expands and contracts as temperatures change. As long as the vinyl can move as required, staples could work, although not my choice, roofing nails driven by hand is my preferred method of fastening. If one leg of the staple is in the slotted hole and the other beyond the edge, and it is not tight to the plywood so there is a little room for movement, the staples will work. If the leg of the staple is IN the vinyl, it is locked in place, and will not move as needed. The very short pieces that are nailed in that way can be the exception, since they are so short, movement will be negligible. Also for what it is worth, one staple can be driven to lock an end or middle in place, as long as the rest of the staples allow the vinyl to move elsewhere.

Just as a mention, why is the installer putting up vented soffit when the backer is solid. The perforations will be of no use. Typically the soffit goes directly to the framing if the soffit needs to be vented....

Comment: Could the vents reduce condensation in this application? Also are those few holes in the plywood possibly an attempt to ventilate the space above?

Comment: @Kris, n my experience, condensation occurs on non-permeable surfaces, metal being the biggest offender that I have seen. Since vinyl is non-permeable, it could form on the surface that is exposed, and since the humidity can readily get to the back of the vinyl, now it COULD form on the back, but vinyl does not rust or degrade with moisture, and the backer appears to be painted plywood so the condensation, if any, will have little effect on the backer. The holes you may be looking at, are screw heads holding the backer in place. I spotted phillips head screws...

Comment: I’m looking at the larger holes and imagining that   more will be added as the soffit install progresses it could add more air flow into attic

Comment: Kris is correct I told them too add holds for ventilation. Just hope bees don't find a way in